# Windows Boot Error Loop

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron

I just updated Windows to find that when I start my computer, the Dell boot screen is displayed and the following error message is displayed:

> Windows could not complete the installation. To install Windows on this computer, restart the installation.

I am running Windows 10 on a Dell Inspiron 7000 series. I forgot the exact model and I can't access Windows. I understand this may not be the correct page to post this on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Windows accidentally went into audit mode. Try the following steps (source below)

Method 1: Enable Administrator Account

1.On the error screen press Shift + F10 to open Command Prompt.

2.Type the following command and hit Enter: MMC

3.Next click File > Add/Remove Snap-in.

4.Select Computer Management and then double-click on it.

5.In the new window that open select Local computer and then click Finish followed by OK.

6.Then double-click Computer Management (Local) > System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Users > Administrator.

7.Make sure to Uncheck Account is disabled option and click OK.

8.Next, right click on Administrator then select Set Password and set a strong password to get started.

9.Finally, close everything and restart your PC. After the restart, you may be able to Fix Windows Could Not Complete The Installation.

Method 2: Start Account Creation Wizard

1.Again open the Command Prompt on the error screen by pressing Shift + F10.

2.Type the following command and hit Enter: cd C:\windows\system32\oobe

3.Again type “msoobe” (without quotes) and hit Enter.

4.The above will start user account creation wizard, so create a generic account and it’s password.
Note: Keep your product key ready as sometimes it is required. If it asks for OEM/No then simply hit finish.

5.Once done hit Finish and close everything. 
Restart your PC

Method 3: Change Password Requirements

This error tends to pop-up when in Audit Mode and the computer has just been joined to a domain. The error is caused by password requirements added to the local security policy. This typically includes a minimum password length and password complexity.

1.Open the Command prompt on the error screen.

2.Type the following the command and hit Enter: secpol.msc

3.Navigate to Account Policies > Password Policy.

4.Now change “Minimum password length” to 0 and disable “Password must meet complexity requirements.“

5.Apply the changes and then exit the Security Policy console.

6.Click OK on the error message to reboot your PC.

Method 4: Registry Fix

1.On the same error screen press Shift + F10 to open Command Prompt.

2.Type the following command and hit Enter: regedit

3.Now in the Registry Editor navigate to the following key: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status

4.Adjust the following values if they don’t match the following:

Note: To change the value of the below keys double click on them and then enter the new value.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\AuditBoot                                              Value: 0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\ChildCompletion\setup.exe               Value: 3
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\ChildCompletion\audit.exe                Value: 0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\SysprepStatus\CleanupState             Value: 2
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\SysprepStatus\GeneralizationState  Value: 7
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\UnattendPasses\auditSystem            Value: 0

change the value of setup.exe under ChildCompletion from 1 to 3

5.After a Reboot the Audit Mode is disabled and Windows starts regularly – in the Out of Box Experience mode.

Method 5: Disable Audit Mode

Running sysprep command each time resets Windows licensing the state to default. So if your Windows is activated and you run this command, you’ll need to reactivate Windows after executing this command.

1.Open Command Prompt on the error screen.

2.Type the following command in the cmd and hit Enter: sysprep /oobe /generalize

3.This will disable the Audit Mode.

4.Close everything and reboot your PC normally.

5.If you’re still facing this issue then again open cmd.

6.Type the following command and hit Enter: regedit

7.Navigate to the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\State

8.Highlight State Registry key, then right click on ImageState in the right window pane and click on Delete.

9.Once you deleted the string, close everything and restart your PC.

source:

http://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-windows-could-not-complete-the-installation/

Comment: I tried those methods after googling a similar issue that happens with windows 7. None of them worked so I decided to do a soft reset and it's working now. Thanks for the help though!